# How to evaluate the statement *ptr1++ = *ptr2++?

Tags: c

I'm wondering how to actually evaluate the following statement , what does it exactly do ?

```
*ptr1++ = *ptr2++;
```

Does it firstly assign the value of that the pointer is pointing at and then increments ?

Is it the same as writing the following ;

```
*ptr1 = *ptr2
ptr1++;
ptr2++;
```

Does the equal sign actually have higher precedence than the increment sign (++) ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Does the equal sign actually have higher precedence than the increment sign (++)?` - No, but `something++` returns the old value rather than the new one. Also, look at [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: It says that assignment operator (=) is evaluated RL but the increment (++) LR does that mean that the evaluation is wrong or am I just reading it wrong ?

Comment: Associativity only matters within the same level of precedence.

Comment: @Thomas Sourtzis: Where does it say that "assignment operator (=) is evaluated RL"???

Comment: copy one thing from where ptr2 points to where ptr1 points then increment both pointers. Idiomatic from `while(*s2++ = *s1++)` string copy one liner

Comment: @AnT Last table of the column on [the cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). It’s what enables you to do things like `a = b = 1` to set `a` and `b` to `1` instead of `a` to `b` and then `b` to `1`.

Comment: @Daniel H: That's not dependent on the order of evaluation. The table simply says that `a` will receive the value of `1` intermediately converted to the type of `b`. No RL order of evaluation is necessary for that.

Comment: @AnT With LTR evaluation, it would be `(a = b) = 1`. I was wrong about what effect that had, but it’s still not equivalent. It’s actually a compiler error because `a = b` isn’t an lvalue (at least in C; in C++ it compiles but only sets `a` and not `b`).

Comment: @AnT That’s still associativity, not order of evaluation, but since `=` isn’t commutative they’re fairly related even if they aren’t the same thing. Not reliably, especially not in a multithreaded environment, but the OP’s comment was posted before the answer explaining the difference.

Comment: @Daniel H: No, it wouldn't be. Neither LTR not RTL evaluation is allowed to violate the required semantics, dictated by associativity and precedence. LTR evaluation in this case would be `a  = (type of b) 1; b = 1;`. RTL evaluation would be `b = 1; a  = (type of b) 1;` or `b = 1; a = b;` (compiler's choice). All variants produce the same outcome. You are mixing LTR associativity with LTR order of evaluation. These are very different concepts.

Comment: Language concept of *order of evaluation* is very different from from the *order of evaluation* taught is school math. The major reason of that difference is that C evaluations are generally not *pure* - they have side-effects.

Comment: @AnT Yes, it is. But when the OP claimed it was evaluated RTL, he still didn’t understand that; he made that comment before you posted your answer. It’s an easy mistake to make because a compiler which always evaluated things in associativity order would be correct, even if other options are also possible.

Comment: @DanielH there is nothing as "evaluating things in associativity order", those things are not related.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Compilers can (output code to) evaluate things in any order they want as long as they obey the sequencing rules. But if a compiler were to always evaluate the LHS of an expression where the main operator was LTR associative before evaluating the RHS, and vice versa if the main operator was RTL associative, such an implementation would be conforming. This is also the most natural order to go in when hand-evaluating a program. Therefore, the mistake of thinking that order of evaluation and associativity are related, while still a mistake, is understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to introduce temporal relationships (like "firstly" and "then") to understand the meaning of this statement. In fact, describing it in terms of "firstly", "secondly" and such would be misleading.

Operator precedence tells us that it should be interpreted as

```
*(ptr1++) = *(ptr2++);
```

i.e. it tells us that in both cases `++` applies to pointers, not to pointed values. That's all operator precedence tells us, no more. Operator precedence and associativity does not define *order of evaluation* (and actually have nothing to do with it).

The fact that postfix form of `++` is used means that the result of `ptr1++` subexpression is the *old, original, non-incremented* pointer value (same for `ptr2++`). So, the unary `*` operators are applied to the original pointer values.

This tells us that the assignment operator copies data stored at the location *originally* pointed by `ptr2` to the location *originally* pointed by `ptr1`.

Side-effects of this statement (produced by `++` operators) increment both pointers. It does not matter when exactly that happens.

Again, this does not mean that `*` operators are applied and data is copied "firstly" and pointers are incremented "afterwards". The compiler is free to do it in any order, as long as the required semantics is satisfied. It may compile it into code you suggested in your question, or into something completely different. E.g.

```
old_ptr1 = ptr1;
ptr1 = ptr1 + 1;
*old_ptr1 = *ptr2;
ptr2 = ptr2 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) I would say yes and no, the **results** are equivalent, the sequence of the operations might not be.

> quote from the [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)
>
> When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row will
>   be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator
>   that is listed on a row further below it.
>   **For example, the expression `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`, and not as
>   `(*p)++`.**

Comment: Including that last sentence (“The C language standard doesn't specify operator precedence.”) in the quote is misleading. Without the context it seems to say something completely different than was intended, and it is not particularly relevant because precedence is still well-defined even if it is only specified indirectly.

Comment: @DanielH thanks for the feedback, I took it out of the quote.